# Plotting MetPy Q-vectors

Tags: metpy

I'm having trouble plotting Q-vectors from metpy.calc from GFS data; I can't get the vectors to plot correctly when applying the `ax.set_extent` and `ax.quiver`

Calculation code:

```py
import metpy.calc as mpcalc

query.variables('Temperature_isobaric', 'Geopotential_height_isobaric',
                'u-component_of_wind_isobaric', 'v-component_of_wind_isobaric')

data = subset_access.get_data(query)

lat = data.variables['lat'][:]
lon = data.variables['lon'][:]

press = data.variables['isobaric'][:] * units.Pa

# Make the pressure same dimensions as the temperature and winds
pressure_for_calc = press[:, None, None]

temperature = data.variables['Temperature_isobaric'][0] * units.kelvin

u = data.variables['u-component_of_wind_isobaric'][0] * units.meter / 
    units.second

v = data.variables['v-component_of_wind_isobaric'][0] * units.meter / 
    units.second

dx, dy = mpcalc.lat_lon_grid_deltas(lon, lat)
```

Now I was trying to run the dx and dy through the q-vector function:

```py
Q = mpcalc.q_vector(u,v,temperature,pressure_for_calc,dx,dy)
```

But I was getting an error I believe was related to the dx and dy dimensions:

```py
IndexError: too many indices for array

dx.shape, dy.shape
>>> ((101, 160), (100, 161))
```

Ok, so that was clearly a problem; I need a 1d array for each, so I probed the shape of the temperature array:

```py
print(temperature.shape)
>>> (31, 101, 161)
```

So I tried taking a subset of the dx and dy:

```py
print(dx[:,0].shape, dy[0,:].shape)
>>> (101,) (161,)
```

Then I figured this should line up with the temp and press arrays and I tried the calculation again based off these subsets:

```py
Q = mpcalc.q_vector(u,v,temperature,pressure_for_calc,dx[0,:],dy[:,0])
```

No errors, feeling good now. Checking the dimensions of Q which I assumed to be the x and y-components:

```py
 print(Q[0].shape, Q[1].shape)
 >>> (31, 101, 161)
 >>> (31, 101, 161)
```

Seems to line up...

However, when I look at the dimensions of lats and lons:

```py
lat.shape, lon.shape
>>> ((101,), (161,))
```

It seems to be backwards from the shapes of dx and dy?

Am I missing something or did I just go about calculating the Q-vectors completely wrong? This was my first attempt and I'm not sure if what I was doing was correct in the first place.

The real problem comes when I try and plot them with any projection with `ax.quiver`

Plotting code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature

# Set Projection of Data
datacrs = ccrs.PlateCarree()

# Set Projection of Plot
plotcrs = ccrs.LambertConformal()

# Add Map Features
states_provinces = cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature(category='cultural',
    name='admin_1_states_provinces_lakes',scale='50m', facecolor='none')

country_borders = cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature(category='cultural',
    name='admin_0_countries',scale='50m', facecolor='none')

# Lat/Lon Extents [lon0,lon1,lat0,lat1]
extent = [-130., -70, 20., 60.]
```

```py
# Create a plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(17., 11.))

# Add the map
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection=plotcrs)

# Add state boundaries to plot
ax.add_feature(states_provinces, edgecolor='k', linewidth=1)

# Add country borders to plot
ax.add_feature(country_borders, edgecolor='black', linewidth=1)
```

```py
lon_slice = slice(None, None, 8)
lat_slice = slice(None, None, 8)

ax.quiver(lon[lon_slice],lat[lat_slice],Q[0][0,lon_slice,lat_slice], Q[1][0,lon_slice,lat_slice],
color='k',transform=plotcrs)

ax.set_extent(extent, datacrs)

plt.show()
```

Resulting map:

[image]

When I leave out the `ax.set_extent` it seems to plot the Q-vectors, just with no map background now...

[image: no ax.extent]

So I guess my two questions are:

1) Did I calculate the Q-vectors appropriately from the GFS data?

2) What am I missing for the plotting?

Comment: I would assume based on the precedence of `query` you are using Siphon to get your data? If so, would you be able to share what specific GFS dataset you are accessing? The issue you are having looks like it would be dependent on the grid your data is on and the dimensionality of your data.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Siphon to get the GFS global 0.25 deg data. I've been using the same projections to plot this data for other variables before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I think you calculate the Q-vectors properly, but there was a simpler solution. The error occurred because you were passing 2D arrays of `dx` and `dy`, but your fields `temperature` and `pressure_for_calc` are 3D. NumPy doesn't know that it should repeat the dx and dy for each height level. You can accomplish this without subsetting by:

```
Q = mpcalc.q_vector(u, v, temperature,pressure_for_calc, dx[None, :], dy[None, :])
```

What this does is insert a size 1 dimension as the first dimension for `dx` and `dy`, leaving the remaining dimensions unaffected. This allows everything to line up properly with the other arrays.

As far as plotting is concerned, this is a classic CartoPy gotcha. Your call to `quiver` should look like:

```
ax.quiver(lon[lon_slice], lat[lat_slice],
          Q[0][0,lon_slice,lat_slice].m, Q[1][0,lon_slice,lat_slice].m,
          color='k', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

Note the change to pass `transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()`. This is how to tell CartoPy that the data you are passing to quiver are in a longitude/latitude coordinate system. This also assumes that the vectors you are plotting are properly referenced in this coordinate system--they should be since you passed `dx`, `dy` calculated from `mpcalc.lat_lon_grid_deltas()`. Note in this case, since CartoPy is going to be doing some reprojection of the vectors, you need to use `.m` to drop the units.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks so much for the insight! The dx, dy make sense now since that's how I recalculated the pressure to match the dimensions also. Q-vectors now plot perfectly. Thanks again for the help with the theory as well as the implementation.